# How to generate XML OutPut in stored Procedures

Tags: xml, oracle

I will be getting few records from database using SQL query in a stored procedure , My requirement is that I need to convert these records in to XML format and send this XML as an OUT PARAM in the same stored Procedure.

Can you kindly help us

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML can turn a query into XML.  For example:

```
select DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML (q'!
    select 1 value1, 'asdf' value2 from dual union all
    select 2 value2, 'fdsa' value2 from dual    
!') from dual;
```

Returns a CLOB with this data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <VALUE1>1</VALUE1>
  <VALUE2>asdf</VALUE2>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <VALUE1>2</VALUE1>
  <VALUE2>fdsa</VALUE2>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

In a stored procedure, select this into an OUT CLOB parameter.

Comment: Hi Jonearles .. I implemented it , Its working fine :-) Thank u so much!!

Answer (score 2):

If your requirements are more complicated than being able to use just a SQL statement as suggested by jonearles, another option is the XMLDOM package, which will allow you to create XML using PL/SQL.

It's more complicated than DBMS_XMLGEN, but it's also more powerful.

Comment: As of now above suggested one is working , If I face any diffucluty I will go thorugh your suggestion also .. Thanks :-)